# I read a txt file to Java and I want to make it be encoded as edges where each edges is a pair of nodes(DFS)

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, collections, java-8

The text file looks like:
0 1

0 2

0 3

1 133

1 194

2 20

2 115

2 116

5 231.....

So what I wanna do is read my txt file and store each line content(because each edge is made by a pair of nodes) in an linked list, I tried this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class readfile{



 public Scanner x;
  public void openFile(){
    try{
      x = new Scanner(new File("facebook_combined.txt"));
    }

catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("could not open file");
}
}

  public void readFile(){
    LinkedList<Integer,Integer> adj = new LinkedList<Integer,Integer>();
    while(x.hasNext()){
      String a = x.next();
      int resa = Integer.parseInt(a);       
      String b = x.next();
      int resb = Integer.parseInt(b);
      adj.add(resa, resb);
      System.out.println(adj);
    }
  }

  public void closeFile(){
    x.close();
  }
}
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    readfile r = new readfile();
    r.openFile();
    r.readFile();
    r.closeFile();
  }
}
```

But it's return an error that linked-list only allow one type which means I can't store a pair of nodes that is connected to each other.

So is there any other way to store edges(a pair of nodes)?

I'm a real fresh man in java field and I'm tring to learn this language better, I would appreciate for any suggestion!

Comment: You *read* a text file in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java any `List` is an ordered collection of elements; but these elements can be objects of **ANY** class. So, the idea is that your element should be the unit of concern in your business logic. In your case, this is the pair of numbers. Given this, you could create a custom class called `Edge` for example that will be used as the `element`s of the `List` and have this `Edge` class store the respective pair of number. For example:

```
    static class Edge {
        private int first;
        private int second;
        
        public Edge(Scanner scanner) {
            this(scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt());
        }
        
        public Edge(int first, int second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }

        public int getFirst() {
            return first;
        }

        public int getSecond() {
            return second;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Edge [first=" + first + ", second=" + second + "]";
        }
    }
```

Then in your code change:

```
LinkedList<Integer,Integer> adj = new LinkedList<Integer,Integer>();
```

(which actually won't compile since `List` requires only a single generic type, not two) and replace it with:

```
List<Edge> adj = new LinkedList<Edge>();
```

making `adj` a `List` of `Edge` objects.

- Additional Tips:

You could also take advantage of Java 8 streams and enhanced NIO Apis and rewrite the entire transformation of the text file to a `List<Edge>` with the simple following method:

```
    public static List<Edge> readEdges(String filename) throws IOException {
        try (Stream<String> linesStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))) {
            return linesStream
                    .map(line -> new Edge(new Scanner(line)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
```

Finally, the following is a full working demo of this approach, run it to get a feeling for it:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class EdgesReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Edge> edges = readEdges("PATH/TO/MY/EDGES/TEXT/FILE");
        System.out.println(edges);
    }

    public static List<Edge> readEdges(String filename) throws IOException {
        try (Stream<String> linesStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))) {
            return linesStream
                    .map(line -> new Edge(new Scanner(line)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
    
    static class Edge {
        private int first;
        private int second;
        
        public Edge(Scanner scanner) {
            this(scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt());
        }
        
        public Edge(int first, int second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }

        public int getFirst() {
            return first;
        }

        public int getSecond() {
            return second;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Edge [first=" + first + ", second=" + second + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a59080158)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you already mention an error shows `linked-list only allow one type`. the root cause is LinkedList support one type based on the doc java.util.LinkedList https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

To allow LinkedList to store edges, we have to solutions :

1. We could create Edge class which contains two integer elements that represent the from_note and the to_node.
   And we know LinkedList is a generic class, LinkedList could store any type inside LinkedList.
2. We could use int[] to represent the edge. And the first element inside the array is from_note and the second element inside the array is to_node.

And there are other things we could improve the code.  such as class naming. you could follow Google Java Style Guide https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html

When we learn a new class or new java library, we could go over the class by looking into their doc like https://docs.oracle.com to understand the meaning of the function, and parameter.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    // solution 1: by introduce Edge class
    public static class Edge{
        int from;
        int to;
        public Edge(int from, int to){
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return from+"->"+to;
        }
    }

    public static class readfile{
        public Scanner x;
        public void openFile(){
            try{
                x = new Scanner(new File("facebook_combined.txt"));
            }

            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("could not open file");
            }
        }

        public void readFile(){ // solution 1: represent edge by using Edge class
            LinkedList<Edge> adj = new LinkedList<Edge>();
            while(x.hasNext()){
                String a = x.next();
                int resa = Integer.parseInt(a);
                String b = x.next();
                int resb = Integer.parseInt(b);
                Edge edge = new Main.Edge(resa, resb);
                adj.add(edge);
                System.out.println(edge);
            }
        }

        public void readFile1(){ //solution 2: represent edge by using array
            LinkedList<int[]> adj = new LinkedList<int[]>();
            while(x.hasNext()){
                String a = x.next();
                int resa = Integer.parseInt(a);
                String b = x.next();
                int resb = Integer.parseInt(b);
                int[] edge = new int[]{resa, resb};
                adj.add(edge);
                System.out.println(edge[0] + "->"+ edge[1]);
            }
        }

        public void closeFile(){
            x.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readfile r = new readfile();
        r.openFile();
        r.readFile();
        r.closeFile();
    }
}
```